# ASP.NET MVC Kendo Grid how to call controller method from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Because I have a custom modal confirmation popup, I'll need to call the the method `.Destroy("Remove", "Attachment")` from javascript. How do I call the `Remove` method from javascript? I've indicated in the code `how to call` where I'd like to be able to call the method. Also, how to pass through the `OrderViewModel`?

Here's my grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikAspNetCoreApp7.Models.OrderViewModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.OrderID).Filterable(false);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Freight);
            columns.Bound(p => p.OrderDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
            columns.Bound(p => p.ShipName);
            columns.Bound(p => p.ShipCity);
            columns.Command(command =>
            {
                command.Custom("Destroy")
                    .Click("showDeleteConfirmation")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:40%" });
            }).Width("15%");
        })
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Filterable()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .Destroy("Remove", "Attachment")
            .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "Grid"))
            .Destroy(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "Grid"))
        )
)
```

The modal:

```
@(Html.Kendo()
        .Dialog()
        .Name("DeleteConfirmation")
        .Modal(true)
        .Title("Confirm Delete")
        .Content("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
        .Visible(false)
        .Actions(a =>
        {
            a.Add().Text("No").Action("cancelDelete");
            a.Add().Text("Yes").Action("confirmDelete").Primary(true);
        })
)
```

The scripts:

```
<script>
    var modelToDelete;

    function showDeleteConfirmation(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var dialog = $('#DeleteConfirmation').data("kendoDialog");

        modelToDelete = grid.dataItem($(e.target).parents('tr'));
        dialog.content("Are you sure you want to delete this item with ID - " + modelToDelete.OrderID + "?");
        dialog.open();
    }

    function confirmDelete(e) {
        //how to call .Destroy("Remove", "Attachment") from here
    }

    function cancelDelete() {
    }
</script>
```

The controller:

```
public ActionResult Remove([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, OrderViewModel attachmentVm)
{
    Attachment attachment = _db.Attachments.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Guid == attachmentVm.Guid);
    attachment.IsActive = false;
    attachment.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
    attachment.LastUpdatedBy = _sessionUser.Username;
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
function confirmDeleteAttach(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Attachment/Remove',
        data: { Guid: modelToDeleteAttach.Guid },
        type: "POST",
        success: function () {
            gridToDeleteAttach.dataSource.remove(modelToDeleteAttach);
            $('#DeleteConfirmationAttach').data("kendoDialog").close();
        }
    });

}
```